# Determine whether a Date only inline DatePicker, is currently in a calendar view mode, or a shortcut month/year rotary view mode

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uikit

Currently, I have an **inline** style `DatePicker` with **Date** only mode.

### calendar view mode

[image]

The DatePicker is observing value changed event, and will execute `datePickerValueChanged` if value changed event happen.

For the above screenshot, if I try to tap on the date 16, the following function callback will be executed

```
@IBAction func datePickerValueChanged(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    print(">> datePickerMode => \(datePicker.datePickerMode.rawValue)")
    print(">> datePickerStyle => \(datePicker.datePickerStyle.rawValue)")
}
```

However, if I were to tap on the local top left "February 2021" (Will not cause `datePickerValueChanged`), it will become the following

### month/year rotary view mode

[image]

If I rotate the rotary view, the same `datePickerValueChanged` will be executed as well!

I would like to perform some action, only if user tap on a date during calendar view mode.

Since both of the views will trigger value change event, and checking for `datePicker.datePickerMode` and `datePicker.datePickerStyle.` doesn't help much.

Do you have any idea, how I can determine whether a Date only inline DatePicker, is currently in a calendar view mode, or a shortcut month/year rotary view mode?

Comment: So if the user wants to select the same day but for the previous month (January 15th) they must tap 15 after changing the month even when it is already selected? Maybe better to react to all changes.